# Shell script doesn't create files

Tags: shell, debian

I try to create randomly between 30 and 130 files in a specific folder with a shell script. I might have made some mistakes because I am not working with shell for long time. Here is my code:

```
ran=$RANDOM
while [$ran > 100]; do
  $ran = $RANDOM
done
$ran=$ran+30
i=0
while [$i < $ran]; do
  cat > 'Lobby/data/map_'$i'.dat'
  $i=$i+1
done
```

Hope you can help me. I'm working with debian.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Are there errors? What sort of debugging have you tried so far?  There are some lines there that I would expect to result in syntax errors.

Comment: There hasn't been any error. I think that the whil loop doesn't work

Comment: you dont begin by trying to create 30 random files. you begin by trying to make one file. and then you work from there.

Comment: Hmm I can create one file... But the loop is still wrong

Comment: `[` is just a placeholder for command `test`, if not spaced i'm not sure how bash will process it, but sh won't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (use bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
ran=$(( RANDOM % 100 ))
ran=$(($ran+30))

for (( start = 1; start <= $ran; start++ ))
do
  touch './Lobby/data/map_'$start'.dat'
done
```

or sh:

```
ran=$(( $$ % 100 ))
ran=$(($ran+30))
i=0
while [ "$i" -le "$ran" ]; do
    touch './Lobby/data/map_'$i'.dat'
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
done
```

Make sure you have permissions to write in this folder.
Random % 100 will generate number up to 100 - adding 30 will make sure you are not below 30 or above 130 so no need for additional check like you did.

Regards,
Vedran

Comment: Error: ./bw02.sh: 19: ./bw02.sh: Syntax error: Bad for loop variable

Comment: Yes... my bad - I used bash - add first line of your script: #!/bin/bash

Comment: well... the whole other thing was in shell. Will that work, if the file contains both?

Comment: is this just part of script that you need to insert?

Comment: while [ "$i" -le "$ran" ]; do
    touch './Lobby/data/map_'$start'.dat'
    i=$(( i + 1 ))
    done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109556/discussion-between-vedran-mile-tomljanovic-and-nicola-uetz).

Comment: The `for (( start = 1; start <= $ran; start++ ))` syntax won't work in `sh`